# is it Possible to Trigger Android Toast Notification from Webpage?

Tags: javascript, android

Right now in web pages I sometimes want to send an alert to the user, saying that an Ajax request was successful or unsucessful. Using Javascript's `alert()` function works, but on Android it's a large popup that the user has to interact with before continuing.

Some apps trigger a different sort of message. It's a gray rectangle with rounded corners. It appears near the bottom of the screen and is unobtrusive but noticeable.

[image]

Is there a way to trigger this from Javascript?

**Edit**: I'm running a website, not an HTML5 app, and I don't need the undo functionality, just the messaging.

Comment: "Is there a way to trigger this from Javascript?" -- only if you implement it yourself, as that is not part of Android. "Additionally, is there a specific name?" -- that is a variation on the "snackbar" theme. There is a different view, the `Toast`, that also can be made to appear. However, that is modeless; yours is not, otherwise "Undo" couldn't be clicked. `Toast` is part of standard Android, but browser developers are not required to somehow make a `Toast` available to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether you're running a JavaScript/HTML5 **app** that uses WebView on your android device or if it is just a **website**.

If it is the first case, then there is a way to show **native** Android [toast notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) using Android [JavaScript interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html). This exact problem is solved [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) in Android WebView documentation.

In case you're running a website and you want it to look native on android, you will have to implement a notification on your own and style it so that it looks similar to native toast notification. You can use [jQuery UI tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) with custom styling for that purpose, for example.

Comment: I'm running a site, not an app, so that sucks. But at least I know now, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `JavascriptInterface` callback in your android code.

This allows you to call android function using javascript, where you can call the function to display your toast.

See this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm not running an app.

Comment: Ohh In that case you cannot call native android toast. As @AndyM mentioned, you have to style popup UI.